# Using wikipedia module in python

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I am using wikipedia module in my python code. I would like to have an input from user to search from wikipedia and get 2 lines from its summary. Since there might be many topics with same name, I used like this.

```
import wikipedia
value=input("Enter what u want to search")
m=wikipedia.search(value,3)
print(wikipedia.summary(m[0],sentences=2))
```

While executing this its showing some 3 pages of exceptions. Whats wrong with this?
Edit:
As suggested by @ Ruperto, I changed the code like this.

```
import wikipedia
import random
value=input("Enter the words: ")
try:
    p=wikipedia.page(value)
    print(p)
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    s=random.choice(e.options)
    p=wikipedia.summary(s,sentences=2)
    print(p)
```

Now the error I get is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\vdhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw   File "C:\Users\vdhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err   File "C:\Users\vdhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa) TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\vdhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked, urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03AEEAF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

What to do now?

Comment: What search phrase did you enter? What exceptions is it showing? If you `pip install wikipedia` and run the above code, it works just fine, other than there being a spelling error in the prompt.

Comment: There is no error if I search a name that has only one page in a title under wikipedia. For eg if I search "India" its giving the desired output. If I type "programming" its producing lot of exceptions as there are many kind of pages with that title.

Comment: perhaps this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946692/wikipedia-disambiguation-error  wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError was seen

Comment: Seems like it can't get internet access. Do you use any firewalls, proxies or VPNs?

Comment: Nope I dont use any of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may due to No/Poor internet connection, as your error says,

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

You can change/check your internet conncetion and try again. Neither, it is problem of your python environment.
My implementation is,

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import wikipedia
import random


value=input("Enter the words: ")
try:
    m=wikipedia.search(value,3)
    print(wikipedia.summary(m[0],sentences=2))
    # print(p)
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    s=random.choice(e.options)
    p=wikipedia.summary(s,sentences=2)
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
Enter the words: programming
Program management or programme management is the process of managing several related projects, often with the intention of improving an organization's performance. In practice and in its aims, program management is often closely related to systems engineering, industrial engineering, change management, and business transformation.
```

It works fine in google colab, my implementation colab file you can find [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18nrqiMMUsjUNPVufOSS5cGqCMippLyrd?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

The above error is due to the connectivity issue of the internet. However the below code works

```
value=input("Enter the words: ")
try:
    m=wikipedia.search(value,3)
    print(wikipedia.summary(m[0],sentences=2))
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    s=random.choice(e.options)
    p=wikipedia.summary(s,sentences=2)
    print(p)
```

However a note of caution here would be that since this is a part of a larger code block it would be better doing a abstractive or extractive summarization using any NLP library as wikipdia package just uses beautifulsoup and soupsieve for web scraping and reverts the just few top lines, in a way that is not summarization. Also the content on wikipedia can change every 2 hours

Comment: The problem is that my code is for a guessing game so any kind of word from any topic could be given(eg. movies,food) So I thought wikipedia module would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem, and after a lot of head-scratching and googling, found this solution:

```
import wikipediaapi as api
import wikipedia as wk

# Wikipediaapi 'initialization'
wiki_wiki = api.Wikipedia('en')


# Getting fixed number of sentences from summary
def summary(pg, sentences=5):
    summ = pg.summary.split('. ')
    summ = '. '.join(summ[:sentences])
    summ += '.'
    return summ


s_term = 'apple'# Any term, ambiguous or not
wk_res = wk.search(s_term)
page = wiki_wiki.page(wk_res[0])
print("Page summary", summary(page))
```

Basically, from what I've seen you don't get a good solution with just the wikipedia module.
For example, If I were to search 'India', I'd never be able to get the page for India the country, which was what I wanted.
This happens because the title of India(Country)'s wikipedia page is just titled 'India'. However, that title is invalid due to the number of things it could refer to. This case applies to a lot of other things as well.

However, wiki_wiki_.page can get a page with an ambiguous title, which is the system this code depends on.